# Make the SuggestionDisplay div go into the correct position

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

In my GWT app I have a GWT `SuggestBox` which I use for a full text search. The problem is that when you scroll in the page while `SuggestionDisplay` is shown, the results move down the page as you scroll.

When I use Firebug to inspect the page, I see that the text box's `<div>` element is in the correct place, but the suggestion display's `<div>` sits right above the closing `</body>` tag. Moving the `<div>` with Firebug into the "wrapper" `<div>` makes the search results sticky as desired (it stays at the top of page).

How can I make the suggestion display go into the right position? `SuggestionDisplay` objects do not have any public methods I can use to manipulate it in any way using the DOM or so. `SuggestBox` constructs it's own `SuggestionDisplay`, and you can provide it too, but even so, how can I make the `<div>` go into the correct position?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the answer right there. You need a custom `SuggestionDisplay`. The `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` uses a PopupPanel, which is placed inside the `<body>` tag by default. Yours should place the div with suggestions inside the container of your SuggestBox then.

Comment: To do this one has to implement your own ``SuggestionDisplay`` from scratch, as well as a ``SuggestionMenu`` and a ``MenuItem``. It is not possible to extend the ``DefaultSuggestionDisplay`` by aggregation or inheritance, because of most of the methods having ``protected`` access. This is more trouble than I think it's worth.

Comment: To do this one has to implement your own ``SuggestionDisplay`` from scratch, as well as a ``SuggestionMenu`` and a ``MenuItem``. It is not possible to extend the ``DefaultSuggestionDisplay`` by aggregation or inheritance, because some essential method have ``protected`` access. If this was possible one could have overridden the ``createPopup()`` method (the only way to set the Popup) to create your own Popup. Rewriting is more trouble than I think it's worth.